# Migrations and Testing CLI Commands Not Working in Visual Studio Code / VSCode Terminal

Tags: testing, visual-studio-code, terminal, migration, command-line-interface

Running both migrations with "npm run migrate" and tests with "npm test" in the terminal in VSCode throws errors, yet if I run the same commands on the same project from the terminal on my mac, they run perfectly and as expected.

- What is the reason for this?
- Is there a way to configure my terminal in VSCode so that I can run migrations and testing through it or do I need to use the always use the terminal on my mac for migrations and testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your project probably contains some specific configuration for mac ios

the visual studio terminal is a powershell

you can test npm by running npm start on powershell

I need more information to be able to help, a print of the error is very useful...